# File upload button lable inconsistent in chome and firefox

Tags: html, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox

For below code

`<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  />`

render button label in inconsistent in chrome and Firefox . (Chrome - Choose file, Firefox - Browse).

[image]

I need this label is to be consistent in any browser. (Prefer everywhere it display as browse).

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden file uploader and put another button,too. then call file uploader by javascript when click on your button

```
<input type=file id=myfileuploader style='display:none'>
<input type=button value='upload' onclick='callUploader()'>

<script>
function callUploader(){
document.getElementById("myfileuploader").click();
}
</script>
```